# Pass django context data to frontend without inline script in template

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-requests, content-security-policy

I'm already passing django context data to my frontend part using inline scripts in my template file:

```
<script>
    var variable = "{{ variable }}";
</script>
```

But for security reasons I'm no longer able to do this. My
Content Security Policy settings should be configured in a way to prevent inline scripts.
Can you help me? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

May be you could use **data-** attribute in tags to pass some values:

`<div data-href="https://www.example.com" data-include-parent="false" data-width="280"></div>`

and then access those by CSP-allowed script